# Error messages while just typing in rstudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

For some unknown reason, Rstudio is generating error messages while I
m just typing (I'm not even pressing ENTER):

```
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
Error in gsub(reStrip, "", completions, perl = TRUE) : 
  input string 1 is invalid UTF-8
> asdfasdjkgfhasjkdfhgaskjdgfhasdjkfh
```

I tried just using R (which works fine) so this is definitly an issue with Rstudio itself. I tried uninstalling/redownloading/reinstalling, without effect.

When I use the sessionInfo()-function i get the following printout:

```
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 11 x64 (build 22621)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.utf8  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.utf8   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.utf8 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.utf8    

time zone: Europe/Paris
tzcode source: internal

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.3       R6_2.5.1         magrittr_2.0.3   gtable_0.3.4    
 [5] glue_1.6.2       tibble_3.2.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3  lifecycle_1.0.3 
 [9] ggplot2_3.4.3    cli_3.6.1        fansi_1.0.4      scales_1.2.1    
[13] grid_4.3.1       vctrs_0.6.3      compiler_4.3.1   tools_4.3.1     
[17] munsell_0.5.0    pillar_1.9.0     colorspace_2.1-0 rlang_1.1.1
```

....Which seems legitimate I guess. What on earth is the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: does it only happen after you load these listed packages?

Comment: @Golem It happens whenever I start the program, I haven' t really gotten around to loading any packages yet.

Comment: Check whether your ~/.Rprofile loads packages or anything else which could trigger this error message. Try not to load any packages automatically in your .Rprofile. 
Another idea would be to first close your current project and to delete your .Rhistory and your .Rproj.user files. Then, reopen your project.